# Is every FOL theory interpretable in a finite FOL theory?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, axioms

Is it the case that: every consistent recursively axiomatized first order theory is interpretable in some consistent finitely and recursively axiomatized first order theory in finite signature?

Comment: You mean $\sf NBG$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I think you got the reverse order of quantification. I meant $\forall T.. \exists G ..$

Comment: I think this is a consequence of the following much sharper result: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326470/does-every-first-order-theory-have-a-finitely-axiomatizable-conservative-exten